# Can't prove that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $A\subseteq\omega_\alpha$ such that $\lvert A\rvert<\aleph_{\alpha}$ then $\bigcup A \in \omega_\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Prove that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $A\subseteq\omega_\alpha$ such that $\lvert A\rvert<\aleph_{\alpha}$ then $\bigcup A \in \omega_\alpha$.

I can't prove that, but I can't prove that it's false either, first I proceeded by contradiction, later by contraposition and failed too. Finally tried with transfinite induction and I didn't make it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: First I proceeded by contradiction: supposed the hypothesis and $\bigcup A = \omega_\alpha$ but I achieved nothing. Then tried by contraposition and transfinite induction, but failed too.

Comment: I'm glad you couldn't 'prove' it: the claim is false. See @DanielWainfleet's answer for a counterexample (the smallest possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False. For example $\alpha=\omega$ and $A=\{\omega_n: n\in\Bbb N\}. $ Then $|A|=\aleph_0 <\aleph_{\omega}$ and $\cup A=\omega_{\omega}=\omega_{\alpha}.$

Reading topic: Regular cardinals and singular cardinals.