# Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal and $B\subseteq \omega_{\alpha}$ such that $\bigcup B=\omega_{\alpha}$ then $|B|=\aleph_{\alpha}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I can't prove this problem. My attempt was choosing $\alpha=\omega$ and watch the process, but i can't get the proof. This was a true/false question. I will be very thankful if someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is false in general, and indeed $\alpha=\omega$ is a counter example (let $\alpha=\omega$ and $B=\{\omega_i\}_{i\in\omega}$, clearly $|B|=\omega<\omega_\omega$, but if $\bigcup B=\beta<\omega_\omega$ then $\beta<|\beta|^+<\omega_\omega$, but $|\beta|^+\in B$ so $\beta>|\beta|^+$, contradiction).

Cardinals $\omega_\alpha$ with this properties (note, the property is of $\omega_\alpha$, not of $\alpha$) are called [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal), and generally, the only cardinals you can show have this property are the successor cardinals and $\aleph_0$.

Uncountable limit regular cardinals is known as [weakly inaccessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal), and they are a form of a [large cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) and we cannot prove their existence is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency) within ZFC.

Comment: asterisk: "cannot prove their existence is consistent within ZFC".

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks, fixed!

Comment: not fixed, 'within' not 'with'

Comment: @BrianO Why not fixed? Two separate issues:  1) ZFC cannot prove their existence (provided it is consistent). 2) Moreover, we can't prove their existence is consistent with ZFC, or more precisely: "ZFC+weakly inacessible cardinals exist" is of strictly higher consistency strength than ZFC.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Fixed now. Your points are of course true, my quibble concerned literally 2 letters.

Comment: @BrianO I think my point didn't get across there (I was saying "with" was not wrong, but in fact superior phrasing to "within"), but I don't want to get into a protracted argument over something this minor.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen nor do I. To briefly explain my thinking, though, we can prove, with ZFC as metatheory, that ZFC + "there is a weak inaccessible" $\vdash$ Con(ZFC), but can't prove existence of such a cardinal *in*/within ZFC. (Unless you disagree vehemently with that, no need to reply!)

Comment: +1. I'm inept at searching but I know the Q is a duplicate (with the same error) because  I answered it in early Jan./ 2022 with the same example.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet looking through your profile, I found [this answer of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4366384/471959) on an duplicated question (not really early Jan, but close)